# Angular 6 nebular 6 get query param in component

Tags: angular, authentication, routes, angular-routing

I'm using Angular 6, ngx-admin theme with it's authentication. I want to pass token id in url for reset password and get that id in reset password form so that i can pass it to backend server. Below is my app-routing.module.ts file:

```
{
path: 'auth',
component: NgxAuthComponent,
children: [
  {
    path: '',
    component: NgxLoginComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'request-password',
    component: NgxRequestPasswordComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'reset-password/:token',//here i need token
    component: NgxResetPasswordComponent,
  },
```

And below is NgxResetPasswordComponent file:

```
constructor(protected service: NbAuthService,
          @Inject(NB_AUTH_OPTIONS) protected config = {},
          protected router: Router) {

this.redirectDelay = this.getConfigValue('forms.resetPassword.redirectDelay');
this.showMessages = this.getConfigValue('forms.resetPassword.showMessages');
this.provider = this.getConfigValue('forms.resetPassword.provider');

  console.log(this.router.url);//output: /auth/reset-password/dsadasdasfaf

}
```

I need to get "dsadasdasfaf" from this URL and pass it to form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import `ActivateRoute` first and initialize it

```
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
        let token = params['token'];
        console.log(token);
      });
```